# Native d3.js v5 - constructing a radial scale with desired interval

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a circle and then have a radial linear scale to run along the circumference of that circle. It would be ideal to have the domain of this custom scale to be easily configurable. I think the snippet below gets me pretty close, but the rotate logic is hard to map out. The result should be ticks that represent each item in the (scale/dummy) data array. In this case, 0 to 50:

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

graphGroup.append('circle').attr('r',30).attr('cx',0).attr('cy',0).style('fill',"#003366");

var axisG =   graphGroup.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(0, 60, 10))
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
    if (i<3) {
      return "rotate(" + (-90 + (d * 180)) + ")";
    }
    if (i>3) {
      return "rotate(" + (-90 + (d * 180)) + ")";
    }
  });

  axisG.append("line")
    .attr("x1", 40 - 4)
    .attr("x2", 40 + 4)
    .style("stroke", "black");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

As we can see, the ticks don't get spaced correctly, and wind up all in the same place. Not sure why I can't append the tick lines in a way that follows the granularity of the data in the `data()` portion of `axisG`.

In other words, imagine the circle as going from 0 to 50 about its circumference (0-50 is the spread of my data). 0 and 50 would both occur at 12 o'clock (if it were a clock). Since we are moving in increments of 10, 10 would be 72 degrees from 12 o'clock, 20 would be 144 and so forth.

### Question

What rotate logic would be needed to ensure that ticks are appended as desired? (appending lines at various angles/orientations depending on which tick value / which degree in the overall circle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, but you need to translate numbers to degrees in some way. For instance, you could make a variable called `amountPerRevolution` and set it to `50` if you want it to have 50 for each revolution, then change your transform function to:

```
  var amountPerRevolution = 50;
  //...
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + (-90 + (d * 360) / amountPerRevolution) + ")";
  });
```

Alternatively, a more d3 idiomatic way of doing this is to use a linear scale:

```
var degreeScale = d3.scaleLinear([0, 50], [-90, 270]);
//...
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + degreeScale(d) + ")";
  });
```

#### Snippet:

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;
var amountPerRevolution = 50;
var degreeScale = d3.scaleLinear([0, 50], [-90, 270]);

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

graphGroup.append('circle').attr('r',30).attr('cx',0).attr('cy',0).style('fill',"#003366");

var axisG =   graphGroup.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(0, 60, 10))
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
//      return "rotate(" + degreeScale(d) + ")";
      return "rotate(" + (-90 + (d * 360) / amountPerRevolution) + ")";
  });

  axisG.append("line")
    .attr("x1", 40 - 4)
    .attr("x2", 40 + 4)
    .style("stroke", "black");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```